# I am getting an error with CORS: "Ensure CORS response header values are valid."

Tags: javascript, cors

I am new to using the Pledge donations API. I am making an api call when I click a button. However when I make the request, I receive a CORS error, when I look at the networks tab in google chrome debugger. I am not sure why. I am following the api documentation. It says I only need to include the Authorization key and value like this:

```
# With shell, you can just pass the correct header with each request
curl "https://api.pledge.to/v1/donations" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer {api_key}"
```

And that's what I've done:

```
const endpoint = 'https://api.pledge.to/v1/donations'
const myHeader = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
}
function handleClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     return fetch(endpoint,{
        method:'GET',
        headers: myHeader,
        
    },
    ).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
    }).then((jsonResponse)=>{
        try{
            console.log(jsonResponse);

        }catch(error){
            console.log("there is an error>>>",error);
        }
    });
}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Ensure CORS response header values are valid.

A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) 
request was blocked because of invalid or 
missing response headers of the request 
or the associated preflight request .

To fix this issue, ensure the response to the CORS request and/or 
the associated preflight request are 
not missing headers and use valid header values.
```

I also see that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header has a problem, which says `Missing Header`.

When i test the endpoint on POSTMAN it works. Perhaps I am missing something in my header? Why am i getting request blocked due to CORS? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You may need to set the `credentials` option to `include` in your fetch request. See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included

Comment: It sounds like the API doesn't support CORS, you need to make the call from the server side, not the client.